# Retrive data from two tables and populate DataGrid Entity Framework

Tags: c#, sql-server, database, wpf, entity-framework

I am using Entity Framework. I have 2 tables in my database Customer and Invoice. The invoice Table has a column of CustomerID as foreign key to reference to the customer.
[image: Tables in database]

I am using a `DataGrid` that has the following columns as shown in picture.

[image: Data Grid]

This `DataGrid` should show data from Invoice Table and customer name from customer table. Please help me how to query this ?
**DataGrid**

```
<DataGrid IsReadOnly="False" Margin="0 10 0 0" Background="white" Name="InvoiceGrid" AutoGenerateColumns="False">
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Invoice ID" IsReadOnly="True" MinWidth="100"/>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Date" IsReadOnly="True" MinWidth="100" />
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Customer" IsReadOnly="True" MinWidth="250" />
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Quantity" IsReadOnly="True" MinWidth="80" />
        <materialDesign:MaterialDataGridTextColumn IsReadOnly="True" Header="Total" MinWidth="150" />
```

**Context class**

```
public partial class Intelliventory_DBEntities : DbContext
{
    public Intelliventory_DBEntities()
        : base("name=Intelliventory_DBEntities")
    {
    }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        throw new UnintentionalCodeFirstException();
    }

    public virtual DbSet<Category> Categories { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<Customer> Customers { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<Employee> Employees { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<Invoice> Invoices { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<InvoiceItem> InvoiceItems { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<Product> Products { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<Purchase> Purchases { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<Supplier> Suppliers { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<sysdiagram> sysdiagrams { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If `Customer` is a navigation property of `Invoice`, you could load it using eager loading, e.g.:

```
var context = new Intelliventory_DBEntities();
InvoiceGrid.ItemsSource = context.Invoices.Include(x => x.Customer).ToList();
//...
context.Dispose();
```

You could then bind the column to the navigation property:

```
<DataGridTextColumn Header="Invoice ID" Binding="{Binding InvoiceID}" IsReadOnly="True" MinWidth="100"/>
<DataGridTextColumn Header="Date" Binding="{Binding Date}" IsReadOnly="True" MinWidth="100" />
<DataGridTextColumn Header="Customer" Binding="{Binding Customer.CustomerName}" IsReadOnly="True" MinWidth="250" />
```

Comment: Thanks a lot sir ! stay blessed ..can you please explain me a lil this line context.Invoices.Include(x => x.Customer).ToList();

Comment: Please refer to the documentation: https://learn.microsoft.com/sv-se/ef/ef6/querying/related-data

Comment: okey i just got it that .Include is eager loading forcefully ! can i use lazy loading that is default entity framework phenomenon  ?

Comment: It depends on the lifetime of your context. But please ask a new question if you have another issue.